# Upgrading Spring boot from 2.6.15 to 2.7.0 does not create schema in H2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I've upgraded Spring boot from `2.6.15` to `2.7.0` and unit tests started failing. The error am getting:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop sequence if exists <my-schema-name>.trigger_event_seq" via JDBC Statement
..
....
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "<MY-SCHEMA-NAME>" not found; SQL statement:
drop sequence if exists <my-schema-name>.trigger_event_seq [90079-212]
```

pom.xml

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:flowable;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database=h2
```

schema.sql:

```
CREATE schema <my-schema>;
CREATE schema flowable;
```

With Spring boot `2.6.15` - I was using H2 `1.4.199` dependency added in `pom.xml`. Which I removed after upgrading to Spring boot `2.7.0`. As H2 `2.x` has fix vulnerabilities. I also renamed keys in `test.properties` as per: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-Configuration-Changelog and removed `=MVCC=true` from `url`. I tried adding `;MODE=LEGACY` to `url` but that also failed. I have then updated `url` value to `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:flowable;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema-name` but got the same error.

I'm not sure why `my-schema-name` is not getting created.

Any help is highly appreciated.